# Is "If you haven't finished your MR..., please finish it..." correct?

Tags: conditional-constructions, adverbial-phrases

Is the sentence below correct?

> If you haven't finished your MR (morning reading), please finish it
>   during the lunch break.

I want to send this message to our study group to remind people finishing their MR, which is their daily assignment.

As for me, the sentence seems all right. But after I checked the grammar of [The Zero conditional](http://www.perfect-english-grammar.com/zero-conditional.html), it seems the sentence is not acceptable.

If the above sentence is wrong, can I change it to 'For those who haven't finished the MR, please finish it during the lunch break'?

Answer (score 1):

Your original sentence

> If you haven't finished your MR(morning reading), please finish it during the lunch break.

is correct and understandable.

Your second sentence might be

> For those who haven't finished *their* MR, please finish it during the lunch break.

Comment: Thanks for your correction on the second sentence. It's very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

This is nothing to do with the "zero conditional"

That covers two present tense indicative clauses:

> If you press the button, the light turns on.

But you have an imperative clause. So the page about "zero" conditionals doesn't apply. This is not a first, second or third conditional!  This is a form used to give instructions that apply in a particular situation.

> If you drink, don't drive
>   If it's raining, take your umbrella.
>   If you haven't finished MR, please finish it in morning break.

All correct grammar.  See http://www.grammar.cl/english/conditionals.htm for a brief discussion. and https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/251986/is-it-ok-to-use-imperative-after-a-conditional at our sister site.

Comment: thanks a million. It's very nice of you. I think I get it after your explanation.